# How to create a pipeline in Matillion Data Loader from Facebook Content Insights?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, matillion

I am unable to create a pipeline to get data from Facebook Content Insights to Snowflake. I have generated the page access token from Facebook graph explorer & added that as a parameter- "OAuthAccessToken".

Error-

```
#434 [Query Facebook] - Parameter Validation Failure:

SQL Query - [190] (#190) This method must be called with a Page Access Token.
```

Can someone please help?

Thanks

Comment: According to the [Facebook access token documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens/), the Graph Explorer tool generates short-lived User access tokens that are valid for 1 hour. But it looks like Matillion Data Loader needs a Page Access Token instead.

Comment: Hi @53epo
Yes.
But I am not able to figure out how to add the Page Access Token in the Matillion Data Loader Pipeline. It asks us to authorize using OAuth but no mention of Page Access Token